# Ionic 2 re-usable page component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a reusable page component but ionic has a mess of transclusion bugs.

I've tried to make a page-list-base:

```
<ion-header *ngIf="header || hasHeader">
    <ion-navbar>
        <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="header"></ng-container>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
   <!-- TODO: abstract refresher once it can be put in a component without ion content -->
   <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="pageListBase.refresh($event)">
     <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh"
                          refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
     </ion-refresher-content>
   </ion-refresher>
   <list-base #pageListBase [filter]="filter" 
                            [baseProvider]="baseProvider" 
                            [config]="config" 
                            [template]="itemTemplate">
   </list-base>
   <ion-footer *ngIf="footer">
       <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="footer"></ng-container>    
   </ion-footer>
 </ion-content>
```

I reuse this page here:

```
<page-base [header]="headerTemplate"></page-base>

<ng-template #headerTemplate>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar align-title="center">
      <ion-buttons start>
          <button ion-button>Save</button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
</ng-template>
```

and also here:

```
<page-base #pageBase [header]="headerTemplate"></page-base>

<ng-template #headerTemplate>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar align-title="center">
      <ion-buttons start>
        <button ion-button>button</button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title start>
          Back Button is hidden behind the header
      </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
</ng-template>
```

I've made a [repo to express the problem Here](https://github.com/granthoff1107/Ionic-Tabs-Sandbox)

**Reproduce:** 
Click on a profile picture avatar,

**Bug**: Header Template Appears but the back button is bound to the parent header.

**Attempts to fix**

1.If you remove the `Ion-Header` from the outside it creates Margin Bug.

2.If you remove the `Ion-Header` from the inside, the styles of ion-buttons changes

I'd prefer not to use a rabbit-hole of css fixes. 
How can I create a reusable ionic page component without breaking ionic's layout or functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to me that you are actually rendering `<ion-header>` and `<ion-navbar>` twice: you have them in the `page-base` template where the ng-container includes another pair of `<ion-header>` and `<ion-navbar>`.

So, what I did and worked perfectly:

page-base.html:

change:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar align-title="center">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="header"></ng-container>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

to:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="header"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Please read the full Question, As I stated "2. If you remove the Ion-Header from the inside, the styles of ion-buttons changes"  Doing this will change the style of button in the header i.e rendering the button as blocks with different styles. See my repo for an example

Comment: I tried your code and changed it according to my answer, and I see absolutely no difference in the header (searchbar + save button to the right, white bg, black text), and the back button appears as expected. However, if I remove the ion-header and ion-navbar tags from about.html, then the style does change indeed. I don't know the exact reason for that, it may be a bug..

Comment: if the headers styles are fine than that means it’s the other bug, and the first item is hidden behind the header because ion-content doesn’t respect the header.